# Does my Aloe vera plant need a new pot?

Tags: propagation, aloe, repotting

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me.

I bought this Aloe Vera plant a few weeks ago and it has been growing new leaves ever since. So I'm wondering if I should repot it into a bigger pot or just seperate the new leaves into another pot.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want it bigger then I'd repot but it should be happy in that pot for a while